# Muxltiplexer implementation in HDL

Tags: hardware

I am working through the NAND2Tetris course but I can't figure out how to implement a multiplexer using OR, NOT, and AND gates. I did manage to string together an AND gate and an OR gate which was close, but it failed on a single row of the truth table.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

First create a truth table for the multiplexor. Let's assume the inputs are called `a` and `b`. The select input is `s`. If `s` is '0' the output `o` is equal to `a`. If `s` is '1' the output is equal to `b`.

```
a b s o
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1
```

Now turn the truth table into a boolean equation:

```
o = !abs + a!b!s + ab!s + abs
```

This can be further simplified to:

```
o = s (!ab + ab) + !s (a!b + ab)  
o = sb + !sa
```

That's it for a 2:1-muxltiplexor.